# airflow SparkSubmitOperator failing because: Initial job has not accepted any resources; error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, airflow

I am working in a MAC with the following docker-compose file that inclused airflow and a cluster of pyspark in standalone mode:

```yaml
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Basic Airflow cluster configuration for CeleryExecutor with Redis and PostgreSQL.
#
# WARNING: This configuration is for local development. Do not use it in a production deployment.
#
# This configuration supports basic configuration using environment variables or an .env file
# The following variables are supported:
#
# AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME           - Docker image name used to run Airflow.
#                                Default: apache/airflow:|version|
# AIRFLOW_UID                  - User ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 50000
# AIRFLOW_GID                  - Group ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 50000
#
# Those configurations are useful mostly in case of standalone testing/running Airflow in test/try-out mode
#
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME   - Username for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD   - Password for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS - Additional PIP requirements to add when starting all containers.
#                                Default: ''
#
# Feel free to modify this file to suit your needs.
---
version: "3"
x-airflow-common: &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-jordi-airflow:2.0.0}
  environment: &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ""
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: "true"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "false"
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: "airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth"
    #_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-pip install apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on: &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"',
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}

  # flower:
  #   <<: *airflow-common
  #   command: celery flower
  #   ports:
  #     - 5555:5555
  #   healthcheck:
  #     test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
  #     interval: 10s
  #     timeout: 10s
  #     retries: 5
  #   restart: always
  #   depends_on:
  #     <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
  #     airflow-init:
  #       condition: service_completed_successfully

  ######################################################
  # SPARK SERVICES
  ######################################################

  jupyterlab:
    image: andreper/jupyterlab:3.0.0-spark-3.0.0
    container_name: jupyterlab
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
      - 4040:4040
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
  spark-master:
    image: andreper/spark-master:3.0.0
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 7077:7077
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources
    mem_reservation: 2g

  spark-worker-1:
    image: andreper/spark-worker:3.0.0
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    environment:
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512m
    ports:
      - 8082:8081
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    mem_reservation: 2g
  # spark-worker-2:
  #   image: andreper/spark-worker:3.0.0
  #   container_name: spark-worker-2
  #   environment:
  #     - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
  #     - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512m
  #   ports:
  #     - 8083:8081
  #   volumes:
  #     - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
  #   depends_on:
  #     - spark-master

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
  shared-workspace:
    name: "spark-volume"
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "none"
      o: "bind"
      device: "/Users/jordicrespoguzman/Projects/custom_airflow_spark/dags"
```

I can execute a pyspark code in the jupyter lab container and it works without problems, but when I run the following DAG:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.http.sensors.http import HttpSensor
from airflow.sensors.filesystem import FileSensor
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_submit import SparkSubmitOperator
from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import csv
import requests
import json

from test import execute_spark

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "email": "admin@localhost.com",
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
}


def printar():
    print("success!")


with DAG(
    "forex_data_pipeline",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    downloading_rates = PythonOperator(task_id="test1", python_callable=printar)


    operator = SparkSubmitOperator(
        task_id="spark_submit_job",
        conn_id="spark_conn",
        application="/opt/airflow/dags/test.py",
        total_executor_cores="1",
        executor_cores="1",
        executor_memory="2g",
        num_executors="1",
        name="airflow-spark1",
        verbose=False,
        driver_memory="2g",
        conf={
            "spark.master": "spark://spark-master:7077",
            "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "false",
            "spark.shuffle.service.enabled": "false",
        },
    )

    downloading_rates >> operator
```

I obtain this error from the terminal:

```
Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

and this is the logs from airflow:

```py
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/forex_data_pipeline/spark_submit_job/2021-06-05T00:00:00+00:00/16.log
[2021-06-06 18:17:54,956] {taskinstance.py:851} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: forex_data_pipeline.spark_submit_job 2021-06-05T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-06-06 18:17:55,498] {taskinstance.py:851} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: forex_data_pipeline.spark_submit_job 2021-06-05T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-06-06 18:17:55,528] {taskinstance.py:1042} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-06-06 18:17:55,553] {taskinstance.py:1043} INFO - Starting attempt 16 of 17
[2021-06-06 18:17:55,616] {taskinstance.py:1044} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-06-06 18:17:56,000] {taskinstance.py:1063} INFO - Executing <Task(SparkSubmitOperator): spark_submit_job> on 2021-06-05T00:00:00+00:00
[2021-06-06 18:17:56,071] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 334 to run task
[2021-06-06 18:17:56,310] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'forex_data_pipeline', 'spark_submit_job', '2021-06-05T00:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '57', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dag_spark.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmplw_gag3t', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpdp5gkyr2']
[2021-06-06 18:17:56,481] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 57: Subtask spark_submit_job
[2021-06-06 18:17:57,001] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: forex_data_pipeline.spark_submit_job 2021-06-05T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host 72eec67484fb
[2021-06-06 18:17:57,428] {taskinstance.py:1257} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=admin@localhost.com
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=forex_data_pipeline
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=spark_submit_job
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-06-05T00:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2021-06-05T00:00:00+00:00
[2021-06-06 18:17:57,642] {base.py:74} INFO - Using connection to: id: spark_conn. Host: spark://spark-master, Port: 7077, Schema: , Login: marcelo, Password: XXXXXXXX, extra: None
[2021-06-06 18:17:57,676] {spark_submit.py:364} INFO - Spark-Submit cmd: spark-submit --master spark://spark-master:7077 --conf spark.master=spark://spark-master:7077 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=false --conf spark.driver.port=8083 --conf spark.blockManager.port=51814 --num-executors 1 --total-executor-cores 1 --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 2g --driver-memory 2g --name airflow-spark1 /opt/airflow/dags/test.py
[2021-06-06 18:18:25,835] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[2021-06-06 18:18:25,863] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.1.2.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
[2021-06-06 18:18:25,873] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
[2021-06-06 18:18:25,893] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[2021-06-06 18:18:25,975] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[2021-06-06 18:18:31,946] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:31 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[2021-06-06 18:18:45,384] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
[2021-06-06 18:18:45,641] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:45 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.1.2
[2021-06-06 18:18:47,179] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:47 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
[2021-06-06 18:18:47,233] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:47 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
[2021-06-06 18:18:47,265] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:47 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
[2021-06-06 18:18:47,278] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:47 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: pyspark-4
[2021-06-06 18:18:47,844] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:47 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 2048, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
[2021-06-06 18:18:48,285] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:48 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpus at 1 tasks per executor
[2021-06-06 18:18:48,388] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:48 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
[2021-06-06 18:18:50,399] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:50 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: airflow
[2021-06-06 18:18:50,531] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:50 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: airflow
[2021-06-06 18:18:50,537] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:50 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
[2021-06-06 18:18:50,544] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:50 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
[2021-06-06 18:18:50,546] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:50 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(airflow); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(airflow); groups with modify permissions: Set()
[2021-06-06 18:18:55,387] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:55 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 8083.
[2021-06-06 18:18:55,784] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:55 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
[2021-06-06 18:18:56,441] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:56 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
[2021-06-06 18:18:56,812] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:56 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
[2021-06-06 18:18:56,815] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:56 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
[2021-06-06 18:18:56,904] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:56 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
[2021-06-06 18:18:57,050] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:57 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-1c1ee504-d748-4590-a348-772157d408a3
[2021-06-06 18:18:57,200] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:57 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 1048.8 MiB
[2021-06-06 18:18:57,378] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:18:57 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
[2021-06-06 18:19:00,432] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:00 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
[2021-06-06 18:19:01,266] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:01 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://72eec67484fb:4040
[2021-06-06 18:19:03,846] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark-master:7077...
[2021-06-06 18:19:04,809] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:04 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to spark-master/172.21.0.6:7077 after 543 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
[2021-06-06 18:19:05,705] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:05 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20210606181905-0011
[2021-06-06 18:19:05,729] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:05 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 51814.
[2021-06-06 18:19:05,731] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:05 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 72eec67484fb:51814
[2021-06-06 18:19:05,735] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:05 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
[2021-06-06 18:19:05,796] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 72eec67484fb, 51814, None)
[2021-06-06 18:19:05,912] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:05 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 72eec67484fb:51814 with 1048.8 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 72eec67484fb, 51814, None)
[2021-06-06 18:19:05,930] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 72eec67484fb, 51814, None)
[2021-06-06 18:19:05,934] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:05 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 72eec67484fb, 51814, None)
[2021-06-06 18:19:08,745] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:08 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
[2021-06-06 18:19:13,720] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:13 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('/opt/airflow/spark-warehouse').
[2021-06-06 18:19:13,772] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:19:13 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is '/opt/airflow/spark-warehouse'.
[2021-06-06 18:19:23,242] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - ESTOY AQUI¿¿
[2021-06-06 18:20:03,028] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:03 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 4421.1717 ms
[2021-06-06 18:20:03,414] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:03 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0
[2021-06-06 18:20:03,767] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:03 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) with 1 output partitions
[2021-06-06 18:20:03,787] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:03 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0)
[2021-06-06 18:20:03,819] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:03 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
[2021-06-06 18:20:03,827] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:03 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
[2021-06-06 18:20:03,951] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:03 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[6] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0), which has no missing parents
[2021-06-06 18:20:05,161] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:05 INFO AsyncEventQueue: Process of event SparkListenerJobStart(0,1623003603820,WrappedArray(org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo@f7ba1aa),{spark.executor.memory=2g, spark.driver.port=8083, spark.driver.memory=2g, spark.master=spark://spark-master:7077, spark.submit.pyFiles=, spark.app.startTime=1623003524952, spark.driver.cores=1, spark.rdd.compress=True, spark.executor.id=driver, spark.app.name=pyspark-4, spark.executor.cores=1, spark.submit.deployMode=client, spark.driver.host=72eec67484fb, spark.app.id=app-20210606181905-0011, spark.shuffle.service.enabled=false, spark.sql.execution.id=0, spark.cores.max=1, spark.blockManager.port=51814, spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false, spark.sql.warehouse.dir=/opt/airflow/spark-warehouse, spark.serializer.objectStreamReset=100}) by listener AppStatusListener took 1.1323294s.
[2021-06-06 18:20:07,024] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:07 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 11.3 KiB, free 1048.8 MiB)
[2021-06-06 18:20:07,415] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:07 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 6.0 KiB, free 1048.8 MiB)
[2021-06-06 18:20:07,440] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:07 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 72eec67484fb:51814 (size: 6.0 KiB, free: 1048.8 MiB)
[2021-06-06 18:20:07,465] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:07 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1388
[2021-06-06 18:20:07,573] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[6] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
[2021-06-06 18:20:07,587] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:07 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks resource profile 0
[2021-06-06 18:20:22,808] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:22 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[2021-06-06 18:20:37,721] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:37 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[2021-06-06 18:20:52,722] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:20:52 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[2021-06-06 18:21:07,981] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:21:07 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[2021-06-06 18:21:22,799] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:21:22 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[2021-06-06 18:21:37,728] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:21:37 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[2021-06-06 18:21:52,721] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:21:52 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[2021-06-06 18:22:07,735] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:22:07 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[2021-06-06 18:22:22,722] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:22:22 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[2021-06-06 18:22:37,721] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:22:37 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[2021-06-06 18:22:52,721] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:22:52 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[2021-06-06 18:23:07,754] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:23:07 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[2021-06-06 18:23:22,721] {spark_submit.py:526} INFO - 21/06/06 18:23:22 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

If I go to http://localhost:8081/, I can see the application ID always waiting.

[image]
I have tried to execute a spark-submit job in the jupyter container and it give me the same error, I have been looking for something related and I have tried a lot of different things but anything is working, maybe I have set some configuration wrong

Comment: Looks like you have only one worker, and you don't configure `spark.executors.instances`, which by default is 2. You can try if this is really the issue then you can 1) set `spark.executors.instances` to `1` or 2) add one more worker